# What does "rot13" mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, rot13

I try to figure the code here
I don't understand the meaning of "rot13"

```
onclick = "SetCookie('NowTesting', rot13(this.form.t1.value, this.form.t3.value));
```

Comment: Can you not google It http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13

Answer (score 5):

It is a "secret" code transforming 'A..M' to 'N..Z' and vice versa.

Since the English alphabet uses 26 letters, rotating by 13 is its own inverse.

```
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13

A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J -K -L -M

N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W -X -Y -Z
```

Although such an encoding is obvious to decode, it has a history on the early internet of being used to obscure the answers to riddles, movie spoilers, etc. on the old USENET discussion groups.

Answer (score 3):

The rot13 function is not part of standard JavaScript. it is most likely a function provided by a library the page is using.